# What is the simplest way to make a button press to start a method repeatedly (infinite time) in JavaFX?

Tags: java, button, javafx

It would be nice, if I could use a simple timer (seconds or milliseconds) for the repeated method invocation.

If it is possible, I would use another button to stop this method if necessary.

```
@FXML
private void handleinfiniteActionButton(ActionEvent event) {
    methodToRunInfiniteTime();
}
```

Comment: a loop perhaps?

Comment: I'm not sure, loop is a good idea. Should I make a new thread and invoke sleep() method? (I am novice in Java...) Could you help me out with code example? Thx!

Comment: @ronaldinhogaucho you should create a custom thread object. It should containe a boolean attribute (this will be your stop flag) and a loop inside the run method. When you click the button start the thread. When you click the stop button, set your flag to false, to make the thread exit the loop.

Comment: @vincrichaud Thx! could you give me a code example, please! Thank you!

Comment: I'd recommend to have a look at javafx Concurrency or use a PauseTransition

Comment: fx has extensive threading support tailored to the needs of the ui ... please do some research and then come back with a concrete problem (in the form of a [mcve]

Comment: @ronaldinhogaucho no I won't give you all made code. As you stated you are a novice, you will learn and remember better if you look by yourself, than if you copy a code. Moreover, I gave you the main idea and the different notions you have to look for. Now you might be able to do it by yourself ;-)

Comment: @vincrichaud I tried your solution, but the new thread I made can't have the access to an object that is used by the main thread (I get a nullPointerException). Do you have any idea, what to do?

Comment: @ronaldinhogaucho NPE are not due to access problem. You may have forgot to pass some instance from a class to another

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to modify the GUI from the method, use a `Timeline` and make a `KeyFrame` invoke the method.

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
    Label display = new Label();
    Button playPause = new Button();

    IntegerProperty property = new SimpleIntegerProperty(0);

    // this invokes the logic once per second
    Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1), evt -> {
        property.set(property.get()+1); // replace this with your method call
    }));
    timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);

    display.textProperty().bind(property.asString());
    playPause.textProperty().bind(
            Bindings.when(timeline.statusProperty().isEqualTo(Status.RUNNING))
            .then("pause").otherwise("play"));

    playPause.setOnAction(evt -> {
        // toggle running/paused timeline
        if (timeline.getStatus() == Status.RUNNING) {
            timeline.pause();
        } else {
            timeline.play();
        }
    });

    VBox vbox = new VBox(playPause, display);

    Scene scene = new Scene(vbox);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Otherwise simply use a `ScheduledExecutorService` to schedule the execution on another thread.

```
Button playPause = new Button("play");

ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor(r -> {
    Thread t = new Thread(r);
    t.setDaemon(true); // don't prevent program from exiting
    return t;
});

playPause.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

    ScheduledFuture<?> future;
    volatile int counter = 0;

    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        // (un)schedule the task
        if (future == null) {
            future = executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
                System.out.println(counter);
                counter++;
            }, 1, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            playPause.setText("pause");
        } else {
            future.cancel(false);
            future = null;
            playPause.setText("play");
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: Thx! Timleline class is great, but it makes my program freeze (memory leaks?)...

Comment: @ronaldinhogaucho if you're doing a long-running operation in the code you invoke in the `KeyFrame` event handler, the issue is the same as blocking the javafx application thread in any other way...